# Is there an ftp command on linux that works with ftps

Tags: linux, ftps

Have been trying for 2 hours with lftp commands and any combinations/variations of them but won't connect.

```
lftp :~> user usr pwd;
lftp usr@:~> set ftp:ssl-force true;
lftp usr@:~> set ftp:ssl-protect-data true;
lftp usr@:~> open ftps://site;
---- Resolving host address...
---- 1 address found: ip.ip.ip.ip//<-I removed that                            
lftp site:~> ls
---- Connecting to site (ip.ip.ip.ip) port 990
**** Socket error (Connection refused) - reconnecting
---- Closing control socket
```

Changing to port 22 gives me:

> gnutls_handshake: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.

With filezilla I can connect choosing protocol sftp ssh protocol but that doesn't allow me to automate sending a bunch of files in different locations so I have to click myself silly to get them there.

**[update]**

Any combination of `set ftp:ssl-auth TLS-C`, `set ftp:ssl-auth TLS`, `set ftp:ssl-auth SSL` or combinations without `set ftp:ssl-force true;` or combinations without `set ftp:ssl-protect-data true;` give me the same handshake problem when using port 22

Thank you for reading my question and hope you can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when using port 22

Your server doesn't run FTPS on port 22. It runs **SFTP**. Those aren't the same thing – the former is FTP+TLS, the latter is SSH File Transfer. So the handshake error happens because *lftp* is trying to talk TLS to an SSH server.

```
$ lftp
lftp :~> open sftp://localhost
lftp localhost:~> ls /etc
drwxr-xr-x  145 root     root        12288 Oct  3 16:06 .
drwxr-xr-x   22 root     root       122880 Sep 22 17:44 ..
```